# How to add PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON for SQLite on VB Net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Working on VisualStudio with SQlite

I create my tables with

```
Dim mainTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type VARCHAR(20))"

Dim tableA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (partA VARCHAR(20), userID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES users(userID) ON DELETE CASCADE)"
```

On the sub where I want to delete on cascade I know the value of **userIDtoDelete** (previously selected on a DataGrid) and I have this connection

Dim connDeleteUser = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDataBase.sqlite;Version=3")

```
    Try
        Using (connDeleteUser)

            connDeleteUser.Open()


            Dim sql = "DELETE FROM actos WHERE userID = ?"

            Dim connDeleteUser As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, connDeleteUser)

            connDeleteUser.CommandText = sql

            connDeleteUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userIDtoDelete)

            connDeleteUser.ExecuteNonQuery()

            'I don´t know if this line is neccesary
            connDeleteUser.Close()


        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

I know I need to declare PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON but I can´t figure out how

I tryed things like:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

connDeleteUser.PrepareRetries(@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON)

connDeleteUser.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"

Dim sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE userID = ? PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PRAGMA is an SQL statement; it must be executed like any other SQL statement:

```
someCommand.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"
someCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Anyway, you can simply add the `Foreign Keys = True` option to the connection string.

Comment: Ups!!! Foreign Keys = True was the easyest solution !!! Thanks. I know I need to use this setting when I create tables, add and delete data. I think is not neccesary when I only search the database but anyway I will use on any connection. Thanks a lot.